# Passing chained inputs to strftime

Tags: c#, bash, shell, datetime, jq

I am reading data from a Dynamo table and am trying to parse the input in `jq`. The date column is in C# ticks so I am trying to convert it to a normal datetime format that I can actually make insights with. I keep getting:

```
Assertion failed: (jv_get_kind(j) == JV_KIND_ARRAY), function jv_array_get, file jv.c, line 324.
Abort trap: 6
```

This is the code snippet I am trying to use:

```
getting_data_from_dynamo | jq -r '[(.compoundid.s | split("-")[0]),
(.compoundid.s | split("-")[1]), .typeid.n, (.datetime.n | tonumber | . 
- 62135596800 | strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))] | @csv'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I was doing the math wrong for the datetime tick conversion, the correct code looks like this:

```
getting_data_from_dynamo | jq -r '
  (.compoundid.s | split("-")[:2]) + 
   [.typeid.n, 
   (.datetime.n
    | tonumber 
    | (. - 621355968000000000) / 10000000 
    | strftime("%F %X"))] 
  | @csv'
```

Comment: you're right, also would need `flatten` at the end as well